# How to get and set field format for all the fields in a pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I have created **EditTextField** in PDF using iTextSharp library. I can able to set **FieldName** to **EditTextField**. I also want to set **DataFormat** to it. I will get XML file containing only FieldName and Value. So While merging Value to PDF Template, I want to check the **DataFormat**  and according to that I want to convert the value and set.

I have added a EditTextField. I can able to add name to textfield. I want to add format (Like DateTime format) to TextField. So that next time I can able to fetch all the text fields from PDF and check the format and according to the format, I can able to set the data to it programmatically.

[image]

```
TextField _DOBtext = new TextField(pdfStamper.Writer,
    new Rectangle(40, 670, 110, 650), "patient-dob");
_DOBtext.SetFormat("DateFormat", "mm/dd/yyyy"); // we want to set format like this.
pdfStamper.AddAnnotation(_DOBtext.GetTextField(), 1);
pdfStamper.Close();
```

And while processing the same PDF for filling data, we will first check the AcrofieldName, and logic is written below (its not working code)

```
var GetField = pdfStamper.Acrofields.Field.where(u=>u.Key == "patient-dob").FirstOrDefault();
var Format = GetField.GetFormat(); // we want like this feature
if (Format != null) {
    if (Format.Type = "DateTime") {
        value=string.Format(data, Format.FormatString));
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField(fieldId, value); //fieldId = "patient-dob"
    }
}
```

Please help me to Set and get the DataFormat

(ediit: add iTextSharp tag)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that iText doesn't support something like `SetFormat()` and `GetFormat()` is because *the PDF format doesn't support it*.

You might notice, however, that Adobe Acrobat allows you to specify a field format. The way that they do this is via a JavaScript file that they ship with all of their products. If other PDF renderers (such as Chrome, Firefox or IE) support this I don't know. This JS file has a bunch of built-in functions that they can use for *client-side* validation and one of those function is `AFDate_FormatEx()`. You can see how that lays out in a PDF in this screenshot:

[image]

You might have noticed my emphasis above on *client-side* validation. That's because this is JS which is optional in the spec and it isn't required when programmatically interacting with forms. However, if you are trying to mimic Adobe's product you might want to go down this path. You can programmatically retrieve these settings via something like:

```
var aditionalActions = reader.AcroFields.Fields["patient-dob"].GetWidget(0).GetAsDict(PdfName.AA);
```

And you can set it via something like `SetAdditionalActions()` on your `PdfFormField`.

This is probably a really fragile path but it might work for you.

**However**, for me I'd try something different and just hijack another field that I know that I'm not going to use. Looking through the spec I think I'd just pick something like `/TM` which is just a string used for the field's name when exporting data (I think via FDF or HTTP POST).

```
var _DOBtext = new TextField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 110, 650), "patient-dob");
var tf = _DOBtext.GetTextField();
tf.MappingName = "patient-dob:date:mm/dd/yyyy";
```

And to retrieve it:

```
var mappingName = reader.AcroFields.Fields["patient-dob"].GetWidget(0).GetAsString(PdfName.TM);
```

You can come up with whatever format you want for this entry, as long as it makes sense to you. I'd recommend keeping the field's original name as part of it and then picking whatever delimiters work for you. The value should travel safely with the PDF regardless of the rendering application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. I am trying to add your logic to my code and post the status once issue fixed.

Comment: What is the name of the file analysis tool that produced those screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I wrote a library to manage PDF AcroForm fillup.. this the a sample code from my fill function:

```
    private string fill_form(string output_file)
    {
        using (PdfReader _pdfReader = new PdfReader(FormPath))
        {
            using (PdfStamper _pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(_pdfReader, new FileStream(output_file, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                _pdfStamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = true;

                foreach (var _field in _pdfStamper.AcroFields.Fields)
                    foreach (TemplateField _spField in _lstFields)
                    {
                        if (_field.Key.Equals(_spField.Name))
                        {
                            switch (_spField.Type )
                            {
                                case TemplateFieldType.Text:
                                    _pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key, _spField.Value);
                                    break;

                                case TemplateFieldType.Checkbox:
                                    //TODO: check Value field cannot be set != OnValue, Offvalue
                                    if (_spField.Value == _spField.OnValue)
                                        _pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key, _spField.OnValue);
                                    else
                                        _pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key, _spField.OffValue);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                _pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            }
        }

        return output_file;
    }
```

As you can see in the inner loop I do something similar to your needs.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Type will be **TemplateFieldType.Text** only. 
But text contents might be Date(mm/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm), PhoneNumber [(xxx)-xxxx-xxxx], Substring(Starting Position,Length), etc. 
So While Creating **FormPath** PDF template, we need to provide Type of data( DataFormat) information also. 

`_pdfStamper.AcroFields.Fields.DataFormat("Substring",StartPos,EndPos)` 

and While filling outputFile, I must able to set data according to that format 
`_pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetField(_field.Key,_spField.Value,Format.Type);`

Comment: I got this... it was already clear.. but since you are not describing which error you got from your code (that you state as *non working*) I cannot suggest you nothing more specific than a working code to allow you to access a given field.

Comment: The Step you have sent is working fine. But It only set Data. So there is no issue in that code. But What if a number of PDF files present and One PDF wants **DateTime** in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and another PDF wants "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm", we cannot hard code the DateFormat value. So What I want is : I want to provide format information also while creating **TextField**. I tried to add Format. But there were no option to add it. So posted here hoping that I may get solution.  Eg: **key=patient-dob** and **value=07/08/2016 03:33:22** In pdf I have to display in "dd/mm/yyyy" format ie.,**07/08/2016**

Comment: are you sure that 'changing' the format is something that can be done after the field creation?

Comment: No. While creating Field only we need to provide Format Information also

Comment: then you only need to format the string you put in the field? correct?

Comment: if you need to change the format of a field and then reformat such field you can use my approach.. I build a library that uses an XML file to store all fields values and format as also the reference to the acroform pdf file. When I need to fillup the form the library 'read' the xml (along with pdf) and looks for field settings, format the content of the field and then fillup the acroform.
If you need this I can share my code with you...

Comment: The scenario will be different. I will create 10 PDF Editable templates give it to my clients. Clients have XML file which contains Key and Value. So In C# code, I will search Key and fill Value. But I need know the Format to fill. Simply I can't Set Data.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I tried to provide key as well as Data format in XML file. Its like Config File. But my client is not satisfied with that file. He doesn't want two files.

Comment: you can create a bundle zipping them togheter ... something like .docx

Comment: I think that yuo need to talk with iTextSharp coder itself.. maybe it can give you some hint... he's a StackOverflow user too: Bruno Lowagie

Comment: Thank you for assisting and providing information. I will check with him.

Comment: I'm unable to contact him. I'm new to stackoverflow. I can't find any option to message him.

Comment: you have to add the tag itextsharp by yourself I'm unable to do retagging at this moment

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me  (using iText7)

```
textBox.SetAdditionalAction(PdfName.F, iText.Kernel.Pdf.Action.PdfAction.CreateJavaScript("AFDate_FormatEx(\"yyyy-mm-dd\");"));
textBox.SetAdditionalAction(PdfName.K, iText.Kernel.Pdf.Action.PdfAction.CreateJavaScript("AFDate_KeystrokeEx(\"yyyy-mm-dd\");"));
```

thanks to the iText RUPS tool.